# Alerts system for Discord guilds using Discord.js

Tags: javascript

I have this code running on a Discord bot. It serves as an alerts system for an online game, where it queries an API every so often and appropriately parses a string and sends it to a guild if it matches certain conditions. Though I don't see any problems with it, I have a feeling it could be optimized or trimmed down. Feel free to visit the http://pso2.kaze.rip/eq/ url to see context for the response.

`client` is a [Discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/) client object, and `fs` is a Promisified version of the standard module.

It's supposed to query the URL and parse the data it receives. First, it checks if the first element in the response is different to the one that's cached. If it is, it filters what guilds have the alerts system enabled, and what `ships` they want to be alerted for. (For example: I have a guild that is enabled for ships 3 and 8, so I'll only receive the objects contained in the `eqs` array where `ship` is either 3 or 8)

After that's done, it just builds the formatted message and sends it to the guild and updates the cache once every guild has received their alert.

```
setInterval(async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://pso2.kaze.rip/eq/');
    if (response.status !== 200) return;

    const data = await response.json();
    const cache = JSON.parse(await fs.readFile("./cache.json"));

    if (data[0]["time"] !== cache["time"]) {
        const guilds = await client.guilds.filter(guild => { return client.provider.get(guild, "alerts") });

        for (let guild of guilds) {
            let settings = await client.provider.get(guild[1], "alerts");
            let eqs = data[0]["eqs"].filter(item => { return settings["ships"].includes(item["ship"]) });
            let format = [];

            if (eqs.length <= 0) return;
            if (eqs.length !== 10) {
                for (let eq of eqs) {
                    format.push(`\`SHIP ${eq['ship']}:\` ${eq['name']} (${eq['jpName']})`);
                }
            }
            else {
                format.push(`\`ALL SHIPS:\` ${eq['name']} (${eq['jpName']})`);
            }

            let time = moment(data[0]["when"]);
            let string = `:watch:**IN 40 MINUTES:** (${time.format("HH:mm")} JST)\n${format.join('\n')}`;
            await client.channels.get(settings['channel']).send(string);
        }

        await fs.writeFile("./cache.json", `{ "time" : "${data[0]["time"]}" }`);
    }
}, 50000, client);
```

Comment: I would be nice if you wrote something about what it does...

Comment: I thought it was clear enough. I'll edit my question with more details.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange Code Review!  Please review [How do I ask a good Question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Specifically, it is best to explain what the code does.  This is especially true in the title.

Comment: Thanks, I edited both the question body and the title to be more clear about what the purpose of the code is.